# list with bullet style dots on alternate list elements.

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list of events for a day using lists that looks like the following.

[image]

I want to display the hours in the form of a list as in the image and then highlight the alternate hour. I am not able to get the dots to align perfectly with the borders

```css
body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul {
                flex-direction:column;
                display: flex;
                padding-left:0;
                
            }
            li {
                list-style: none;
                color: #9E9E9E;
                height:24px;
                line-height:24px;
                font-weight:200;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction:row;
            }
            li:nth-child(odd) .ring {
                height: 6px;
                width: 6px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
                -moz-border-radius: 100%;
                border-radius: 100%;
                line-height: 23px;
                background: #cecece;
                margin-top: 9px;
                margin-left: 9px;
            }
            
            #events ul {
                flex-direction:column;
                display: flex;
                padding-left:0;
                margin-top:0;
            }

            #events li {
                list-style: none;
                color: #9E9E9E;
                height:25px;
                width: 48px;
                line-height:25px;
                font-weight:200;
                display: flex;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
                flex-direction:row;
            }
```

```html
<ul class="labels">
                
                    <li><span>00:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>01:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>02:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>03:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>04:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>05:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>06:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>07:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>08:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>09:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>10:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>11:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>12:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>13:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>14:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>15:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>16:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>17:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>18:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>19:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>20:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>21:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>22:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                
                    <li><span>23:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
                <dom-repeat as="hour"><template></template></dom-repeat>
            </ul>
            <ul id="events">
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    
                        <li>
                            <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                        </li>
                    <dom-repeat as="hour"><template></template></dom-repeat>
                </ul>
```

Any tips on how to solve this would be appreciated, also any info on how to draw the various bars inside the second list. Sorry, its not the best example that I could provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed few properties which are all not necesssary. I hove this will help you.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(odd) .ring {
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  -moz-border-radius: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  line-height: 23px;
  background: #cecece;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 7px;
}

#events ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#events li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #9E9E9E;
  height: 24px;
  width: 48px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#events li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cecece;
  width: 56px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="labels">

  <li><span>00:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>01:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>02:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>03:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>04:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>05:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>06:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>07:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>08:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>09:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>10:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>11:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>12:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>13:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>14:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>15:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>16:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>17:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>18:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>19:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>20:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>21:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>22:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>

  <li><span>23:00</span> <span class="ring"></span></li>
  <dom-repeat as="hour"><template></template></dom-repeat>
</ul>
<ul id="events">
  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>

  <li>
    <dom-repeat as="event"><template></template></dom-repeat>
  </li>
  <dom-repeat as="hour"><template></template></dom-repeat>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the job for me. Hope it doesn't cause any other issues anywhere